# javascript split() string after Word that starts with a sequence of characterS

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

This seems like it should be a very easy thing to do but I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

How can I use Javascript split() to split the string after a certain word that starts with say abcd.... so if I have "abcdHello one two three" , I would get " one two three". I am assuming that the abcd.... word will be at the beginning of the string. Thanks!

```
var allClassesString = $('.'+ui.item.overRow).find('.span12').attr('class');
var truncClassesString = allClassesString.split('span^'); // or span* - neither one works.
```

Comment: jQuery has no split function. But JavaScript does. Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it. People seem to be on fire for an honest mistake.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov Feel for you man--ignore the rude ones.

Comment: This seems to be more of a `replace()` than `split()` use-case.

Comment: Not really @DavidThomas . I was really interested in simply truncating my string by removing the abcd... I guess I could have replaced the abcd... word with "" but what Dogbert suggested first, worked perfectly.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov, if that's what you wanted, then `replace` is definitely better.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: I think David is suggesting precisely that—using `replace` to remove parts of a string (by replacing with `""`) is very common in JavaScript. And it returns a string as opposed to an array where the result you want is an element.

Comment: Not really a convincing argument to use `split()`, but it's your script, so whatever you're happy with, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want this:

```
"abcdHello one two three".split(/^abcd\S*/)
=> ["", " one two three"]
```

RegExp explanation:

```
^    -> Start of string
abcd -> Match "abcd" literally
\S   -> Not a whitespace
*    -> Repeat "\S" as many times as possible.
```

After your comment on the question, if you just want to remove the matching text, use `.replace` as @DavidThomas suggested.

```
"abcdHello one two three".replace(/^abcd\S*/, '')
=> " one two three"
```

Add `g` modifier to the RegExp if you want to replace more than one occurance:

```
"abcdHello one two three".replace(/^abcd\S*/g, '')
" one two three"
```

Comment: He wants to get `one two three`, might be worth joining the array back together with `.join('')`.

Comment: @DavidThomas, OP said split, so not sure if he just wants to replace, or split a long string with that delimiter. Will wait for OP's reply first.

Comment: Yeah, it was a suggestion for expanding the answer, rather than replacing it is all.